# How to detect when the user dismisses a interstitial in Admob?

Tags: android, admob

I recently moved my ads to the newer version (now uses com.google.android.gms.ads), but I realised that I am now missing something quite important. I used to be able to detect when the user dismissed their interstitial with OnDismissScreen, but now it looks like this is no longer an option:

I used to do:

```
@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "appid");
  interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest());
  interstitial.setAdListener(this);
}
```

Is there any sort of equivalent in the newer version of Admob?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AdListener#onAdClosed
```

See [Play - AdListener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner#adlistener)

Comment: the onClosed event is not for dismiss of the adview.

Comment: `onAdClosed()` is `Called when the user is about to return to the application after clicking on an ad.`

Answer (score 1):

With AdMob `v20.0.0` the `AdListener` has been deprecated for the full screen ad format.

You should now attach a `FullScreenContentCallback` and override `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` on the `InstertitialAd` instance passed by the `InstertitialAdLoadCallback#onAdLoaded` attached when calling  `InterstitialAd#load`.

In kotlin it should look somenthing like this:

```
    InterstitialAd.load(context, unitId, adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
          // TODO handle error!
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
          interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
              override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                  // TODO Handle here the interstitial dismissed. 
              }
          }
        }
      })
```

If you need more information [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration) you can find the official guide made to migrate to `v20.0.0`

Comment: I see some issues (like delays, missing calls of `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent`), so I still prefer to load a new ad in the onResume(), instead of onAdDismissedFullScreenContent