# How to detect that AdMob interstitial was closed?

Tags: android, admob

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial),

> public void onAdClosed ( )
>
> Called when the user is about to return to the application after clicking on an ad.

But how can I detect that the user closes the interstitial Activity?
(and not the webpage that opened after clicking on the ad)

The accepted answer in this question seems to be wrong:
[How to detect when the user dismisses a interstitial in Admob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486156/how-to-detect-when-the-user-dismisses-a-interstitial-in-admob)

(The interstitial is still visible after the user returns to the app).

Answer (score 5):

With AdMob `v20.0.0` the `AdListener` has been deprecated for the full screen ad formats.

You should now attach a `FullScreenContentCallback` and override `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` on the `InstertitialAd` instance passed by the `InstertitialAdLoadCallback#onAdLoaded` attached when calling  `InterstitialAd#load`.

It should look somenthing like this:

```
    InterstitialAd.load(context, unitId, adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
          // TODO handle error!
        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
          interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
              override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                  // TODO Handle here the interstitial dismissed. 
              }
          }
        }
      })
```

If you need more information [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration) you can find the official guide made to migrate to `v20.0.0`